# Using INNER JOIN to receive crossed data by date range

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a theme gallery. In the dashboard i have to display the most viewed themes BY date (today, last 7 days, last 30 days, all time).

These are the 2 involved tables:

1. **theme**

   - id_theme
   - title
2. **views**

   - id_view
   - id_theme
   - date

The *$timestamp* values are calculated with mktime() (no prob in there).

This is my current SQL query:

```
 SELECT t.id_theme,t.title,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM views
        WHERE views.id_theme=t.id_theme
        AND views.date BETWEEN '.$timestamp1.' AND '.$timestamp2.')
 AS q
 FROM theme AS t
 INNER JOIN views ON t.id_theme = views.id_theme
 GROUP BY views.id_theme
 ORDER BY q 
 DESC LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that The catch, is that sometimes it receives themes with 0 views, and that should not happen. I tried changing the INNER JOIN with RIGHT JOIN with no results. Any ideas?

Comment: hehe thanks, but i'm still struggling for a solution :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. not sure why you're using subqueries for this, seems like this would work better:

```
SELECT theme.id_theme, theme.title, COUNT(views.id_view) as view_count
FROM theme
LEFT JOIN views ON (theme.id_theme = views.id_theme)
GROUP BY theme.id_theme
WHERE views.date > DATE_SUB(now() INTERVAL 30 day)
ORDER BY view_count DESC
HAVING view_count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT t.id_theme, t.title, COUNT(*) AS q
 FROM theme AS t
 INNER JOIN views ON t.id_theme = views.id_theme 
    AND views.date BETWEEN '.$timestamp1.' AND '.$timestamp2.'
 GROUP BY t.id_theme, t.title
 ORDER BY q 
 DESC LIMIT 10
```